# Upgrading @angular/fire from 6.x to 7.x

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm trying to upgrade my app dependencies and my code from @angular/fire 6.x to 7.1.0-rc4 (because I need a feature that is not present in 7.0.x) so I edited my `package.json` with:

```
"@angular/fire": "~7.1.0-rc.4",
"firebase": "^9.0.0",
```

then I changed my imports from:

```
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire';
```

to

```
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/compat';
```

My app is a Ionic5/Angular12 app, so I assume it uses Ivy by default. Looking [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/version-7-upgrade.md), it seems to me I've done everything that was needed to upgrade.

However I get the following compilation error:

```
Module '"@angular/fire/compat"' has no exported member 'AngularFirestore'.ts(2305)
import AngularFirestore
```

Here is my `app.module.ts` file:

```
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule, Optional, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule, BrowserTransferStateModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ServiceWorkerModule } from '@angular/service-worker';
import { RESPONSE } from '@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ComponentsModule } from './components/components.module';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire/compat';
import { AngularFireAuthGuardModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth-guard/';

export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireAuthGuardModule,
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'serverApp' }),
    BrowserTransferStateModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ComponentsModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production }),
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      deps: [PLATFORM_ID, [new Optional(), RESPONSE]],
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Please show how you're importing the module into your project

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what I should show other than the `import` and the `package.json` snippet already present in my question. Can you please explain?

Comment: Your app module where you're initializing the module

Comment: @Hydra here's to you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out the `import`, in the case of `AngularFirestore`, has to be changed for version 7.1 to

```
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
```